# Ubuntu 14 LTS server going to sleep/shutdown

Tags: 14.04, grub2, suspend, power-management, shutdown

We recently transitioned from Ubuntu 12 to Ubuntu 14 server installations and started to notice that the servers are occasionally go to sleep after couple of hours to days intermittently.

Tried/validated these items but did not help:

- BIOS Configuration: disable HDD Power management, keep Fan mode full, Hard disk type to Solid state drive.
- Disabled Power management from the https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25133/ubuntu-server-continuously-goes-to-sleep.  Adding `acpi=off apm=off` to `/etc/default/grub` kept the system running but caused the time to be out of sync with real time clock and ntp could not adjust the time.  Reverted the changes since system cannot be used without actual timestamps.
- HDD power spin cycle status is active (`sudo hdparm -B /dev/sda`)
- Servers are not overheated when the incident occurred
- `boot.log/kern.log/auth.log` has no information/panic about the shutdown as per https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9819/how-to-find-out-from-the-logs-what-caused-system-shutdown
- `auth.log` has no authorized user access.
- last command has output with "down" message

Currently, the systems are running without fail after making these changes:

- Adding `consoleblank=0` to `/etc/default/grub`  This keep console active similar to Ubuntu 12.

  `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="net.ifnames=1 biosdevname=0 consoleblank=0`
- Running `pingdom`/`curl` requests for the server every 5 mins to keep the HDD active. This is short term solution and not positive it is helping anyway.

Question: `consoleblank=0` appears to be working but [has been rejected](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/25133). Does anyone know the inner workings or can share the power/sleep/hibernate mode changes from Ubuntu 12 to Ubuntu 14?